# Rounding decimals in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

I want to display a number as a winning percentage, similar to what you would see on ESPN baseball standings. If the user has no losses, I would like the percentage to read 1.000. If the user has no wins, I would like it to read .000. If the user has a mix of wins and losses, I would like to display .xyz, even if y or y and z are 0's.

This code gets me no trailing 0's, and also a 0 before the decimal (0.4 instead of .400, 0.56 instead of .560):

```
$wpct1 = $wins / ($wins + $losses);
if($wpct1 == 1){$wpct = '1.000';}else{$wpct = round($wpct, 3);}
```

This code gets the initial 0 befoer the decimal out of there, but still no trailing zeroes (.4 instead of .400):

```
$wpct1 = $wins / ($wins + $losses);
if($wpct1 == 1){$wpct = '1.000';}else{$wpct = substr(round($wpct, 3), 1, 4);}
```

This second solution is getting me closer to where I want to be, how would I go about adding the trailing 0's with an additional piece of code (one or two trailers, depending on the decimal), or is there another way to use round/substr that will do it automatically?

Comment: I believe you are looking to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$wpct = ltrim(number_format($wins / ($wins + $losses), 3), '0');
```

This formats the number the three digit after the decimal point and removes any leading zeroes.

See [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) and [`ltrim`](http://php.net/ltrim) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf('%04d',$wpct1);`

Will print leading zeros

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
number_format($wpct, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to add trailing zeros like this:

```
if($wpct1 == 1){$wpct = '1.000';}else{$wpct = str_pad(substr(round($wpct, 3), 1, 4), 3, '0');}
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This traffiic routing answer could have been a comment under the question.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/352329)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [sprintf()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$x = 0.4;
echo sprintf("%01.3f", $x);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.  It's the first parameter that should be explained within the context of this question.  The link to the manual is really just a garnish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's built in [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: This traffiic routing answer could have been a comment under the question.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/352329)